# Does Coronal Mass Ejection (CME) affect my eMMC Storage?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that earth magnetic field is like a shield for Coronal particles. But it will generate magnetic induction

[image: Geomagnetic Storm]

Is my eMMC Storage vulnerable?
Will aluminium foil protect my data?

Comment: I think magnetic fileds may interfere with magnetic storage like HDDs, not flash storage. Silicon cells hold charge, not magnetism. Or is it some other type of interference you are talking about?

Comment: @IrfanLatif thx. now i care more about my computer, although i assume the case will protect as it's like a cage of metal (in contraction to plastic smartphones)

Comment: Well usually the magnetic flux of the Sun isn't strong enough to interfere with the weak flux of storage devices, though I can't remember the exact figures I had studied during engineering course. So in most cases there's nothing to be worried about. But practically I had partially lost my data on some of my magnetic tapes almost 15 years back, when they were unintentionally exposed to magnet of amplifier speakers for a prolonged time, a few months at least. If your PC is a desktop one with big box, it's also shielded in Faraday cage. You can get a sensitive compass to find the flux density.

Comment: https://www.pcworld.com/article/116572/article.html